# Visualization of groups with a normal subgroup_rev#1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, normal-subgroups, visualization

Let $G$ be a group and $H \unlhd G$. In general, $H=H_Z \sqcup  H_{G \setminus Z}$, where $H_Z:=H \cap Z(G)$ and $H_{G \setminus Z}:=H \cap (G \setminus Z(G))$. I'm investigating on a plausible visual model for the pair $(G,H)$. I'll provisionally retain the following one, till some inconsistency will pop up for revision/reject. By "inconsistency" I mean either a contradiction with, or the inability to show, known algebraic facts.

1. $G$ is the euclidean 3-space and $e$ its (geometrical) center;
2. given $g \in G \setminus Z(G)$, the centralizer $C_G(g)$ is a ball whose poles are $g$ and the element $g_{\operatorname{op}}$, opposite to $g$ with respect to $e$ and distant $\mathtt{r}_Z$ from $e$;
3. by 2, $Z(G)=\bigcap_{g \in G}C_G(g)$ is the ball centered in $e$ of radius $\mathtt{r}_Z$;
   [image]
4. given $g \in G$, the right cosets $C_G(g)g'$, $g' \in G$, are eccentric, thick "shells" embedding $C_G(g)$ ("onion"-like); the eccentricity gives the possibility to single out as another partition of $G$ the one made of the left cosets; shell's average thickness is a decresing function of shell's size, so as to get a hint of the bijection between any pair of cosets (constant volume);
   [image]
5. $\forall h \in H_Z$, the conjugacy orbit by $h$ is *pointwise*, being $O_h=\lbrace g^{-1}hg, g \in G \rbrace = \lbrace h \rbrace$;
6. by 5, $H_Z$ is an axis of $Z(G)$ (or anything topologically equivalent to that);
7. once popped out of $Z(G)$, conjugacy orbits become real ones, namely circles around the axis induced by $H_Z$, which globally form a "polar" toroidal surface, embedding $Z(G)$ (this is $H_{G \setminus Z}$);
8. $H$ splits $G \setminus H$ into two regions: an "inner" one and an "outer" one, say $G \setminus H = G_{<H} \sqcup G_{>H}$; given $g \in G_{<H}$, the coset $Hg$ is the toroidal surface by $g$, slicing $Z(G)$; given $g' \in G_{>H}$, the coset $Hg'$ is the surface by $g'$, embedding $H$ and topologically equivalent to a 2-sphere.
   [image]

This model is possibly still far from the "reality", but maybe we can get a better one by addressing some points raised by *this one*:

#1. Does $H$'s closure have some algebraic validity? What would it mean?

#2. Would the special case $Z(G)=\lbrace e \rbrace$ be consistently described by the above model, i.e. with $Z(G)$ "deflated" down to one point?

#3. Given $h \in H_{G \setminus Z}$, are the algebraic loci $C_G(h) \cap H$ and $C_G(h) \cap O_h$ suitably accounted for in terms of the sphere/torus crossing expected from the model?

Comment: Great question! (+1)

Comment: I mean: I don't follow it exactly as it might be beyond me but it looks very interesting, certainly; what I understand of it looks alright to me.

Comment: How did you make the diagrams (*i.e.*, what software did you use)?

Comment: Just MS Office shapes package (Word, PowerPoint,...).

Comment: I can't make head or tail of this.
What is $g_{op}$? What is $r_Z$? etc.

Could you explain what your model looks like for, say, $S_3$? (The smallest non-abelian group.)

Comment: @verret: those are just construction parameters to ideally build up the model "with saw and hammer". The model is thought for infinite groups, so at the moment I wouldn't know haw to tailor it for finite groups.

Comment: Fine, what does your model look like for $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Shaun, I don't understand how you can think it's a great question if you don't understand it. If I have a particular group $G$ in mind, I can't understand what any of the statements (1,2,3,4) actually mean, even before we get to the normal subgroup $H$, let alone the questions at the end.

Comment: I'll try to explain better tonite (CET). Job duty and access to smartphone only all day long today prevent me to do It now. But I understand all the doubts and criticisms, and with pleasure i'll try to reply.

Comment: @verret: Groups are structured sets; sets are visualized as Venn's amorphous shapes, then groups ought to be representable as Venn-like shapes with structures. Abelian groups seems not to be interesting from this point of view; nonabelian ones are, and they are featured by a center smaller than the group itself: this is the first feature to visually address in terms of intersection of all the centralizers (other structures to fit into the model). ...*[continues]*

Comment: @verret: …Normal subgroups are also interesting, as they bring the view of subsets partitioned into conjugacy orbits. If $H \cap Z(G) \ne \emptyset$, then conjugacy orbits in $Z(G)$ are singletons, while those outside of it are not: another fact to account for visually. Finally, all subgroups partition $G$ into cosets (skew or, for normal subgroups, symmetric). And so on. …*[continues]*

Comment: @verret: …Whatever $G$ with these characteristics (is $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}$ such?), the model hopes to represent it *unless some contradiction sets in* (does $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}$ do it)? Anyway, I realize that having given emphasis to the visual aspects, I've been led to deal with more than countably infinite, say "continuous" groups. This is by far beyond my knowledge, so no surprise if the model were to be clearly contradicting some plain fact about them, so to be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading the question as you are asking if there is a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ that satisfy the above properties.  I haven't read through all of your properties, but it is already impossible with properties 2, 3.

Namely, say you have a group $G$ which can be identified with $\mathbb R^3$.  Your property 3 says $Z(G)$ is a ball of some radius, say $r_Z$, about $e$.  (You say sphere, but I assume you mean ball, because certainly you need $e \in Z(G)$.  I will assume the same for property 2.)

Pick any $g \in G - Z(G)$.  Then property 2 says $C_G(g)$ is a ball of some radius $r > r_e$ about $e$.  Take some $h$ in $C_G(g) - Z(G)$ in the interior of this ball.  Then $C_G(h)$ is a ball of radius $< r$ about $e$, but $gh=hg$ means $g \in C_g(h)$.  However $g$ has distance $r$ from $e$, a contradiction.